# xml and xsl cannot loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have an XML:

```
<service>
     <row>
          <column>service1</column>
          <column>service2</column>
          <column>service3</column>
     </row>
</service>
```

I want to loop all the service1 to service3. In XSL I used:

```
<xsl:for-each select="service/row">
    <fo:block>
         <xsl:value-of select="column" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How come it will only output the first column which is "column1"? how do you loop from service1 to service3? I just followed the tutorial in w3schools but cant replicate using this example. What did I miss? I'm just new to XSL and XML.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of a file-system. Your `for-each` loop is looping over each `row` directory in the `service` directory, and printing the value of that row's `column`. Each row has several columns, but `value-of` will only give you the first. You have only one row, so you get only one column.

What you want to do is loop over each `column` directory in each `row` in each `service`. Then you print the value of the current "directory", which, like in Unix, is obtained using the `.` symbol. So, adjust your code like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="service/row/column">
    <fo:block>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and it should all work fine!

Answer (score 1):

You see only the first value because `<xsl:value-of>` outputs *the string value* of its argument.

And the string value of a set of nodes is the text content of the first node - that's how node-sets are converted to string by definition.

Bottom line, you're doing it wrong.

---

```
<xsl:for-each select="service/row">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:for-each select="column" />
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But in reality you shouldn't use `<xsl:for-each>` for things that. Use template matching and `<xsl:apply-templates>`, for example like this:

```
<!-- <service> becomes a table -->
<xsl:for-each select="service">
  <fo:table>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:table>
</xsl:for-each>

<!-- <row> becomes a table-row -->
<xsl:template match="service/row">
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>

<!-- <column> becomes a table-cell -->
<xsl:template match="service/row/column">
  <fo:table-cell>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```